# Redis key expiry event in spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, jedis

I have a key that expires after 30 seconds.

```java
redisTemplate.expire(sessionId , 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This is my listener:

```java
@Service
public class RedisController implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message, byte[] pattern) {
        // Get every expired key from below the code.
        String key = new String(message.getBody());
        System.out.println("expired key is: " + key);
    }
}
```

I have also set `CONFIG SET notify-keyspace-events KEA`, but I am not receiving any callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though your listener looks good, I guess you are missing the configuration of the listener ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49563612/)).

```java
@Bean
RedisMessageListenerContainer keyExpirationListenerContainer(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory, ExpirationListener expirationListener) {
    RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.addMessageListener(expirationListener, new PatternTopic("__keyevent@*__:expired"));
    container.setErrorHandler(e -> logger.error("There was an error in Redis key expiration listener container", e));
    return container;
}
```

I think you might also be interested in (I found them while skimming the JavaDoc API):

- [`KeyExpirationEventMessageListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/2.7.x/api/org/springframework/data/redis/listener/KeyExpirationEventMessageListener.html)
- [`RedisKeyValueAdapter.EnableKeyspaceEvents.ON_STARTUP`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/RedisKeyValueAdapter.EnableKeyspaceEvents.html#ON_STARTUP) used in [`@EnableRedisRepositories`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/repository/configuration/EnableRedisRepositories.html).